# Checking if object inside heap

Tags: python, heap

I am trying to check if an object is inside a heap. However, I keep getting this error:

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'X'
```

I have a `Heap` and a `Cell` class that look like this:

```
import heapq

class Heap(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.heap = []

    def push(self, priority, cell):
        heapq.heappush(self.heap, (priority, cell))

    def pop(self):
        cell = heapq.heappop(self.heap)[1]
        return cell

    def contains(self, cell):
        if(cell in self.heap):
            return True
        return False

    def isEmpty(self):
        return len(self.heap) == 0
```

Cell class:

```
class Cell(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.X = x
        self.Y = y

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return int(self.X) == int(other.X) and int(self.Y) == int(other.Y)
```

I use the `Heap` class like this: I get the error when I use the `contains` method.

```
from Heap import Heap
from Cell import Cell

class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.myHeap = Heap()
        cell = Cell(2, 3)

        self.myHeap.push(1, cell)

        if self.myHeap.contains(cell) == False:
            print("not in heap")

test = Test()
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `self.myHeap` is the `Heap` object from the class `Heap` I made above. Added more code to make it more clear.

Comment: you are pushing `priority` and `Object Cell` in `List` ?? Just Push `Cell` in List and what is `self.myHeap` ? remove `self` then try and tell me what you 've got

Comment: ok you have defined self, did not saw you edited the code

Comment: It's a heap. I need to pass a priority. On the example posted here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html, I can push `tuples` to the `heapq` data structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in `contains`method.

```
def contains(self, cell):
    if(cell in self.heap):
        return True
    return False
```

`self.head` is a list of tuples of type `(priority, Cell)`. And you actually compares `Cells` with elements of this list (tuples), so `Cell.__eq__()` method is called and it raises exception.

Comment: So it's trying to do `(priority, Cell).__eq__()`? Is there a way I can check if the Cell is contained in there then? I can only compare with the `X` and `Y` values I have in `Cell`. Pretty much what I'm asking, is there a way to get the `Cell` object from tuple inside the `__eq__()` method?

Comment: Yes it is, but it  will not be an effective way. Please read [heap queue theory](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html#theory) more carefully. Anyway what you could do is `if cell in [x[1] for  x in self.heap]: ...`.

Comment: Thank you! I'll go over the heap queue theory again.

Comment: What I mean was that heap is actually sorted tree, so you can implement `contains` in logaritmic time and  my *simple* solution has linear time. Anyway after reading that theory you should be able to implement better solution :)